# Force specific price in cart

Tags: prestashop

In certain conditions, I would like to **force a specific price for a given product in a cart** in Prestashop ?

How can I interact with the customer's cart and give him a product discount programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign specific price to certain customers group
2. Add customer to this group

or

Generate on the fly certain cart rule (coupon code) and assign it to the cart

Comment: Thanks Sergii. For the first solution, customer must be logged in which is not always the case. For the second solution, it will add a new voucher to the cart but I want discount price for one product.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood the issue, but this one product, it is a certain product (or product that we can detect using some rules), or any one?  if certain product - possible to create voucher exactly for it.

Comment: Thanks again Sergii. Yes you can create new vouchers but I want the discount to appear on the product line (original price is striked out).